# How do I pass a Java function a String[] argument?

Tags: java, clojure, clojure-java-interop, java-interop

I have a function in Java that I would like to call from Clojure. The particular prototype is the following:

```
public MyClass create(String aaa, File bbb, String[] args)
```

I therefore need to pass a `String[]` as a parameter, from a Clojure function. Passing any of the following:

- (def args `[]`)
- (def args  `[""]`)
- (def args ^String [])

all yield an exception: `No matching method found: createScript for class BlaBla..`

I have also seen [this Java interop documentation](http://clojure.org/reference/java_interop), but I am probably missing something. How do I call this method from Clojure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(.create (MyClass.) "aaa" (File. "my file") (into-array ["foo" "bar" "baz"]))
```

Should do the trick.

See https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/into-array for more details.